# Do these converge for $p>0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Do these converge for **all** $p>0$, $p \in \mathbb{R}$?

- $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^p+1}$
- $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{\ln(n^p)}{n}$

The first one seems to automatically diverge. Take an example where $\;p\;$ is really small. Then $\,n^p=1\,$. Which means it diverges when taking the absolute value of the series, and it doesn't conditionally converge.

The second one has the same problem I guess. $\ln(n)<<<n$, so $\;\dfrac{\ln(n^p)}{n}\;$ is similar to $\;\dfrac{1}{n}\;$ for large enough values of $\;n\;$. Then it converges conditionally, but not absolutely.

Comment: As long as $p>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^p=\infty$.  The first one converges by the alternating series test.  As for the second one, you have to show both that $\log(n)/n$ decreases and goes to $0$ at $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first series converge for all $p > 0$ due to the Leibniz's (alternating series) test.

For the second, let $$f(x) = \frac{p\ln x}{x}$$
then, $$f'(x) = \frac{p(1-\ln x)}{x^2}$$
So, $f(x)$ is decreasing for all $x \ge e$. Again by Leibniz's test, the series converge when $p>0$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** Use the Alternating Series test, which states that for an alternating series $\sum_n (-1)^na_n,$ if $|a_n|$ is a monotonically decreasing series, and $|a_n|\rightarrow 0,$ then the series $\sum_n (-1)^na_n$ converges.